# Close Jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm using below code to open dialog from another another dialog.

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
var cnt = '<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span></p>' + MyMessage;
cnt += '<br/><BR/><input type=button value=Close onClick=$(this).dialog("close") />&nbsp;'; //add two buttons
newDiv.html(cnt); 
newDiv.dialog({ title: "Warning", dialogClass: "error", modal: true })
```

Close button behavior is not working. I've tried $(newDiv) instead of $(this) but it didn't work. Do you've any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's something like `newDiv.dialog("close");` This should work.

You need to specify an event for this though. For example,

```
$("#somebutton").click(function(){
   newDiv = $(".yourdialogdivclass");
   newDiv.dialog("close");
});
```

Comment: nope. am getting 'undefined' error: onClick=newDiv.dialog("close")

Comment: why aren't your `type` and `onclick` values wrapped in ""?

Comment: is `newDiv` defined globally? it would have to be to work in an `onclick`

Comment: He could just define it again in his click function, no?

Comment: I tried using adding class with className property and find it on 'close' button but length was returned zero. I don't know.

I followed @Kebin B suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: I created var at global level, which works in fine IE but not in FF